# In ASP.NET web application what is the difference between F5 and ENTER button press on browser, And also please differentiate across the browsers

Tags: asp.net

In **ASP.NET** web application what is the difference between **F5** and **ENTER** button 
press on browser, And also please differentiate across the browsers.

Answer (score 0):

If you hit enter browser sends a GET request.

If you hit F5 browser sends the last request again. So if last one was a post request (sent form data) it'll ask before sending.

Answer (score 0):

f5 button will send the prior submitted request to the browser. e.g if you hit submit button which saves data in database and if you press f5 the submit button will get executed. Hitting enter will request to webserver for the page you requested. this will create new request to the server. In F5 ISPOSTBACK property will be true even if page is refresh. On hitting enter postback property will be false and again whole page gets loaded

Answer (score 0):

If you hit Enter on the URL it would load from the cache of browser not show changes load **previous state**

if u press F5 it will run the last state of Website (Example if you submit any action on the page it would perform from start to submit function.

My recommendation is that you use Ctrl+R in any browser for perfect result after enter activity

Thanks,

Please mark it answer if its helps you